# Match parenthesis that doesn't contain digit + % only

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm struggling with that one. I want to capture the content of parenthesis where there isn't only `digit %`. This means I would want to capture this `(essiccato, ricco di flavonoidi)` or `(ricco di 23% pollo, in parte essiccato, in parte idrolizzato)` but not this `(23 %)`or `(23)`or `(23 %)`

Here is an exemple : https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/896

So far I'm there : `\([^()][^()]*\)`

Comment: `\([^\d%()][^()]*\)` seems to fit your literal description, but I'm not completely sure why you had the first character class in there initially; I assume you mean that it needs to have some content that *isn't* purely number/percent sign. You should try to clarify your wording and examples if that's not what you're looking for

Comment: `r'\((?!\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s*)[^()]+\)'` - see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qfqTvT/1).

Comment: Post you comment as answer @WiktorStribiżew !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\((?!\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s*)[^()]+\)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qfqTvT/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C((%3F!%5Cs*%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5B.%2C%5D%5Cd%2B)%3F%5Cs*)%5B%5E()%5D%2B%5C)):

[image]

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?!\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s*)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location not immediately followed with

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:[.,]\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of `.` or `,` and 1+ digits
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[^()]+` -  1+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `(...)` are all balanced and there is no escaping of parentheses inside, you may use this regex with a character class and 2 negated character classes:

```
\([\d%]*[^%\d()][^()]*\)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/900)

**RegEx Details**

- `\(`: Match opening `(`
- `[\d%]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that is either a digit or `%`
- `[^%\d()]`: Match a character that is not `(`, `)`, `%` and a digit
- `[^()]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `(` and not a `)`
- `\)`: Match closing `)`

Comment: Yes but there are many things not clear in the question, for example: what to do with `(23,5%)` , `(23   %)`, `( )`, `(1 2 3)` or `(%)`?

Comment: I believe any character that is not a digit and not a `%` should be allowed between `(...)` (as per stated problem in question)

Answer (score 0):

You might use a negative lookahead what follows after the opening parenthesis is not digits followed by an optional percentage sign:

```
\((?!\s*\d+\s*%?\s*\))[^)]+\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `\s*\d+\s*%?\s*\)` match 1+ digits followed by an optional `%` till `)`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[^)]+\)` Match 1+ times any char except `)`, then match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wt7aWG/1)